# Site loads very slow for archive custom post type page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I created a directory website which has a page that displays all the listings (1,005) This page takes VERY long to load. Is there any way to speed this up? Its using a custom post type listing.

There are 1,006 of these queries:

SELECT option_value FROM wp_sulk_options WHERE option_name = 'uninstall_plugins' LIMIT 1
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/debug-queries/debug_queries.php'), Debug_Queries->debug_queries, register_uninstall_hook, get_option

http://www.detroitjewishdirectory.com/listing/

Comment: 1006 of _this exact_ query? 1006 queries similar to it? Just 1006 queries?

Comment: this exact query. It loads all the listings.

Comment: Had you tried disabling plugin, query is coming from?